# Table out of margin while using 'p'

Tags: tables

Any table build with **\begin{tabular}{p{\textwidth}......}** goes out of margin.
An example table is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{.4\textwidth}p{.6\textwidth}}
\hline
example letter & abc... \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am writing my thesis which is a big document with multiple chapters. The preamble of the document looks like this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} % for mathematical operations
\allowdisplaybreaks %allow align to break in pages
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=3.56cm, right=2.54cm]{geometry} % margin
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf} % insert images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % image path
\usepackage[section]{placeins} % figure placement
\usepackage[framed, numbered]{matlab-prettifier} % to insert matlab code
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=space]{caption} % caption formatting
\usepackage{subcaption} % subcaption for subfigure
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for book tabs type table, \toprule...
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell} %break cell in table
\usepackage[T1] {fontenc} % better pdf output
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for controlling item sepaeration
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools} % for using IEEEtran tools in this document 
\usepackage{setspace} % different spacing and stretch
\usepackage{xcolor} % for using colors
\usepackage{times} % times new roman font for the whole document
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % any font size can be used with instead built in \large type
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{float} % uses [H] for figures and tables alignment
\usepackage{url} % for using url in the references
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % no indent
```

Comment: Horizontal spaces are inserted before and after every column, each has width of `.5\tabcolsep`. So you need to specify smaller width for those to `p{...}` columns.

Comment: You mean the space between p{.4\textwidth} &  p{.6\textwidth}?

Comment: I removed the space but it still the same, no change.

Comment: To fix my previous comment: It should be `\tabcolsep`, not `.5\tabcolsep`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

You specified

```
\begin{longtable}{p{.4\textwidth}p{.6\textwidth}}
```

The *usable* overall width is `1.0\textwidth`. However, because of padding on both sides of both columns (in the amount of `\tabcolsep`), the *total* overall width is `1.0\textwidth+4\tabcolsep`. The default value of `\tabcolsep` in many document classes, including `report`, is 6pt. Hence, the `longtable`'s total width exceeds `\textwidth` by 24pt, or roughly one third of an inch (or ca 8.5mm, if you prefer).

To fix this, you should write either

```
\begin{longtable}{p{\dimexpr.4\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
                  p{\dimexpr.6\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
```

or, if you don't need the padding at the left- and right-hand edges,

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{\dimexpr.4\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
                     p{\dimexpr.4\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} @{}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mico, it works perfectly. One more thing, is there any way to get the columns center aligned instead of left aligned keeping the exact same textwidth as here?

Comment: @MAzharulIslam - Certainly: be sure to load the `array` package and to replace `p{...}` with `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{...}`.

Comment: ,Can You help me about another issue I am having in the same table, please? I am using \makecell in the first column, in the first two rows it's behaving ok, but from the third row, it's adding a space in the first line making the sentence starts from the second line. How to remove this first line spacing

Comment: @MAzharulIslam - I'm afraid you haven't provided nearly enough information to allow a diagnosis of what may be going on. May I suggest that you post a new query, with a stylized example of what's going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I am using    \makecell[t]{abc\\def\\syz}

Comment: @MAzharulIslam - Please post a new query.

Comment: I figured out that problem, the width was insufficient, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Why not use  `xltabular`? It combines the features of `longtable` and `tabularx`. To have X columns in a certain ratio, we use the syntax `>{\hsize=xxx\hsize}`, where the coefficients are in the desired ratio, and the sum of the coefficients is the total number of X columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=0.8\hsize\centering}X|>{\hsize=1.2\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}
 \toprule
  example letter & abc... \\ \midrule
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. It's working great. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Some space requires to be left for the separators between each column-- hence the reduction to 0.35 and 0.55

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{p{.35\textwidth} p{.55\textwidth}}
                    \hline
                    example letter & abc... \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: It's not working, I tried to reduce the total \textwidth to .9.

Comment: please upload your code as a MWE in your original question